# Table based declarative reactive programming

Tags: sql, functional-programming, declarative

Is there a programming language or package that supports table based reactive declarative programming in memory very similar to the SQL language and trigger facility?

For example, I could define `PERSON` and `JOB` tables as functions

```
name: PERSON -> STRING
female: PERSON -> BOOLEAN
mother: PERSON -> PEOPLE
father: PERSON -> PEOPLE

title: JOB -> STRING
company: JOB -> STRING
salary: JOB -> INTEGER
empoyee: JOB -> PERSON
```

Then I would like to calculate functions like:

```
childcount: PERSON -> INTEGER
childcount(P) = |{ Q in PERSON : father(Q) = P or mather(Q) = P }|

income: PERSON -> INTEGER
income(P) = SUM { salary(J) : J in JOB and empoyee(J) = P }

incomeperchild: PERSON -> INTEGER
incomeperchild(P) = income(P) / childcount(P)

parent: PERSON x PERSON -> BOOLEAN
person(P,Q) = (P = father(Q)) or (P = mother(Q))

error: PERSON -> BOOLEAN
error(P) = (female(P) and (exists Q in PERSON)(father(Q) = P))
   or (not female(P) and (exists Q in PERSON)(mother(Q) = P))
   or (exists Q in PERSON)(parent(P,Q) and error(Q))
```

So essentially I would like to have calculated columns in tables that are automatically updated whenever values in the tables change. Similar things could be expressed with SQL triggers, but I would like to have such functionality built into a language and executed in memory. The propagation of changes need to be optimized. Are there frameworks to do this?

The observer patter and reactive programming focuses on individual objects. But I do not want to maintain pointers and extra structure for each row in my tables as there could be million of rows. All the rules are generic (although they can refer to different rows via parent/children relations, etc), so some form of recursion is required.

Comment: Ok, my example is really simple. The computations I have in mind are more intricate (interactive web both on server and client side, waiting for results from database, downloading new info, packaging many objects, etc). Of course all of this can be done in straight OOP, but it gets complicated very quickly. Moreover, I would like to defer computing certain columns until other columns are completely calculated. This is hard with OOP, since you cannot just call the update functions,you have to collect changes and commit all modifications at once.

Comment: You might be looking for http://www.espressologic.com

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is via attribute grammars: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Attribute_grammar